# MySQL Match Against In Boolean Mode returns nothing

Tags: mysql, boolean, full-text-search

I am using MySQL Boolean Full-Text Search for fetching college names. The text search works for some values but not for the value '`Others`'

Here is my query -

```
SELECT collegename FROM college
     WHERE MATCH (collegename)
     AGAINST ('+Pune* +institute* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
         order by char_length(collegename)
         LIMIT 10
```

This query gives me result.
However, the following query gives no result

```
SELECT collegename FROM college
     WHERE MATCH (collegename)
     AGAINST ('+Others* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
         order by char_length(collegename)
         LIMIT 10
```

My database has the college with name "Others", still gives no result.

```
ID   CollegeName  Description
XXX  Others       NA
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your query have `AGAINST ('+Others* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` so you need the name of the college be `SOMETHING + Others`. If you only set the name to Others, need remove first plus of the query.

```
AGAINST ('Others* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Drako, `+` indicates that the word must be present irrespective of the order. 'Pune institue gave me the result which included college name which contained the words irrespective of their position' . 'http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean-text-searches.aspx' defines `+`

Comment: Do you have ** Pune institue ** as name of the correct result? `+`  present irrespective of the order but `*` is needed to name like **Others institute** If you only have **Others**, try `AGAINST ('+Others ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: I have tried using `AGAINST ('+Others ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) `, and also changing college name to `Other institute`, still no luck

Comment: Trying in a local test, with the query you used first time:

`SELECT collegename FROM college
WHERE MATCH (collegename)
AGAINST ('+Others* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
order by char_length(collegename)
LIMIT 10`

and with this preview data:

**Pune Institute, Others, Another institute,And others institutes**
return:
**Others, And others institutes**     Do you try to close session on MySQL and login again to refresh data?